# How to show image on google search

Tags: google-search

So if you've noticed when searching for a website or blog, you might end up seeing a picture next to the search result, but it's unclear to me, as how exactly you do that... Can anyone explain how this is accomplished? So far If I had to guess I would say a meta tag...

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is aimed at [webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Sorry... How should I rephrase that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a nice tutorial: http://blog.kissmetrics.com/google-authorship/

And another one for images in general: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/175288?hl=en